# Spark sql using spark thrift server

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to access tables registered in spark using JDBC kind of service, using the thrift service provided by spark.

I didn't got any documentation for this on google, can anyone please tell me how to use thrift server to access spark tables.

and what will be the lifetime of these table in memory, will these table resides in memory till thrift server is running.

Answer (score 1):

The Thrift server documentation is located in the Spark SQL reference page under Distributed SQL Engine (http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#distributed-sql-engine).

If you cache a query the cached result will stay in memory until the Thrift server is stopped.